# Hidden checkbox is still Submitted When i have the checkbox checked

Tags: laravel

```html
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_one[{{$loop->index}}][]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_one[{{$loop->index}}][]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_two[{{$loop->index}}][]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_two[{{$loop->index}}][]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_three[{{$loop->index}}][]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_three[{{$loop->index}}][]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_four[{{$loop->index}}][]" class=" check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_four[{{$loop->index}}][]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_five[{{$loop->index}}][]" class=" check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_five[{{$loop->index}}][]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_six[{{$loop->index}}][]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_six[{{$loop->index}}][]" class="check" value="0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_seven[{{$loop->index}}][]" class="check" value="1"><input type="hidden"  name="level_seven[{{$loop->index}}][]" class="check" value="0"></td>
```

I  have an issue with the checkbox both checkbox and hidden are both submitted when i have the checkbox checked how can i prevent this from happening

Comment: Why do you want a hidden field in a form if you don’t want it submitted??

Comment: the hidden input should be submitted if the checkbox is not checked which is working well if i don't have the checkbox checked. The issue is only whn i have it checked it submits both

Comment: I don’t understand. Why do you need to submit 1 if checked and 0 if not checked? If it’s 1, backend knows it is checked, if not there, backend knows it is not checked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67609000/checkbox-and-hidden-both-passing-value-even-if-checkbox-is-checked-or-not

Comment: Thats the same issue am facing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkbox and Hidden both passing value even if checkbox is checked or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67609000/checkbox-and-hidden-both-passing-value-even-if-checkbox-is-checked-or-not)

Comment: i have tried that but still i have the same issue

Comment: You're over complicating things, you don't need the `hidden` `checkbox` with a value of `0`. If a `checkbox` is not `selected/checked` it is not included in the `POST` `request`. Therefore all you need to do is check the `request` for the presence of a specific key. If it exists your value is `true`/`1`, otherwise `false`/`0`.

Comment: Talk about making a simple feature over complicated!

Answer (score 0):

I have found an easy way to post this though the above various sources claims it works but for me it didn't work the hidden input filed is getting posted regardless but working well when the checkbox is not ticked i changed my form to this

```html
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_one[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_two[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_three[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_four[{{$loop->index}}]" class=" check" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_five[{{$loop->index}}]" class=" check" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_six[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_seven[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"   name="level_eight[{{$loop->index}}]" class=" check" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_nine[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="level_ten[{{$loop->index}}]" class="check" value="1"></td>
```

and in the controller i used this

```html
 $data[] = array(
    'user_id' =>$request->input('user_id'),
    'price_list'=>$request->input('price_list')[$i], 
    'level_one'=>$request->input('level_one')[$i]??'0', 
    'level_two'=>$request->input('level_two')[$i]??'0',
    'level_three'=>$request->input('level_three')[$i]??'0',
    'level_four'=>$request->input('level_four')[$i]??'0', 
    'level_five'=>$request->input('level_five')[$i]??'0',
    'level_six'=>$request->input('level_six')[$i]??'0',
    'level_seven'=>$request->input('level_seven')[$i]??0, 
    'level_eight'=>$request->input('level_eight')[$i]??0,  
    'level_nine'=>$request->input('level_nine')[$i]??0,  
    'level_ten'=>$request->input('level_ten')[$i]??'0', 
    'country_id'=> implode(',', $request->input('country_id',[])[$i]??[]),
    'created_at'=>Carbon::now(),

            
     );
```

so if the the value is empty i used ternary operator to assign it a zero as i intended

Answer (score 0):

You Have to remove name from hidden field after that this is working fine....